# How can I connect objects together within a main statement?

Tags: java

I teach AP CSA (first year) and have decided to give my kids a challenging (to me at least) assignment. They are supposed to use produce a print statement that will tell how long it takes a villain to travel a specific distance. I would like to have a solution BEFORE I give it to them.

The print statement was easy for me, and the program works "as intended"-- I can't help but think I made it too complicated and lost an opportunity to abstract a little instead of hard coding my longitude and latitude. Was there a better way for me to connect the GeoLocation start and GeoLocation end objects to my cities? See below for my code.

```
    GeoLocation start = new GeoLocation(37.765469, 100.015167);
    GeoLocation end = new GeoLocation(37.275280, 107.880066);
    double distance = start.distanceFrom(end);
    double travelTime = distance/15;
    int travelReport = (int)travelTime;


    WesternTown sweatyPost = new WesternTown();
    sweatyPost.saloons = 2;
    sweatyPost.sheriffs = 1;
    sweatyPost.troublemakers = 5;

    WesternTown dodgeCity = new WesternTown();
    dodgeCity.saloons = 7;
    dodgeCity.sheriffs = 2;
    dodgeCity.troublemakers = 29;
    dodgeCity.longitude = 100.015167;
    dodgeCity.latitude = 37.765469;

    WesternTown durango = new WesternTown();
    durango.saloons = 4;
    durango.sheriffs = 0;
    durango.troublemakers = 6;
    durango.longitude = 107.880066;
    durango.latitude = 37.275280;
```

Comment: I've read this a few times and I'm still having difficulty seeing exactly what's being asked here. What's the connection between the towns and location? Could you just put the locations as fields of the towns? Then the math can be tucked away in the class.

Comment: I was trying to have my town instances be recognized by my GeoLocation. Changing it up as described in the second answer worked well-- thank you guys.

Comment: Thank you guys for this answer. I was able to solve all of my other self generated challenges so far-- I am excited to assign the students an option to play a rock-paper-scissors type game of the a high noon gunfight-- Quickdraw beats scattershot-- Scattershot beats drop and fire-- Drop and fire beats quickshot-- Any other ideas of AP Quality challenges my kids can do to a western town project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the `GeoLocation` as a property of a `WesternTown` so it coule be an attribute :

```
public class WesternTown{
    private int saloons;
    private int sheriffs;
    private int troublemakers;
    private GeoLocation location;

    // appropriate constructor with all :
    public WesternTown(int saloons, int sheriffs, int troublemakers, Geolocation location){
        this.saloons = saloons;
        ...
    }
}
```

And you'll have

```
WesternTown dodgeCity = new WesternTown(7, 2, 29, new GeoLocation(37.765469, 100.015167));
WesternTown durango = new WesternTown(4, 0, 6, new GeoLocation(37.275280, 107.880066));

// 1. Leave method in GeoLocation class
double distance = dodgeCity.getLocation().distanceFrom(durango.getLocation());
// 2. or move it into WesternTown
double distance = dodgeCity.distanceFrom(durango);
```

---

1. Leave method in GeoLocation class

   ```
   double distanceFrom(Geolocation other){
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - other.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - other.y, 2));
   }
   ```
2. or move it into WesternTown

   ```
   // move all the method
   double distanceFrom(WesternTown other){
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.location.getX() - other.location.getX(), 2) + 
                        Math.pow(this.location.getY() - other.location.getY(), 2));
   }

   // or just call the Geolocation method
   double distanceFrom(WesternTown other){
       return this.location.distanceFrom(other.location);
   }
   ```

Comment: I like the idea of adding the distance function into WesternTown, but why redo the calculation when you can just wrap the method already made in GeoLocation?

Comment: I think I just did-- I clicked the big check mark anyway! Let me know if I did not do it right since I have read this for years but never actually engaged until today.

Comment: @CluelessAPTeacher You accepted the other answer ^^ I let you know accept the one you want^^ You can obviously accept one answer per question

Answer (score 1):

Add a private `GeoLocation` property to `WesternTown`, and create a public method `setLocation(GeoLocation location)` to set the location. That gets you the benefit of any validations done within `GeoLocation`, and removes the need to set the lat and long yourself.

Then you can simply say `dodgeCity.setLocation(start)` and `durango.setLocation(end)`

Or better yet, include the `GeoLocation` in a constructor and then remove the need to have a setter at all. This is preferable because it really makes no sense for a town to be able to change its location once created.

```
class WesternTown {
    //other properties...
    private GeoLocation location; //<- make sure this is PRIVATE not PUBLIC

    public WesternTown(GeoLocation location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public GeoLocation getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

If you go this route, remove the default constructor (if you have one) to ensure that all towns created have a location.

Now you can easily calculate the distance between any two cities:

```
double distance = dodgeCity.getLocation().distanceFrom(durango.getLocation());
```

Also while not entirely critical, you should probably make the other fields private and include setters/getters for them too. It's more code but it promotes better practices and gets them used to the idea of calling methods to interact with an object's state.

Comment: Thank you-- It is sad that some of my students have better coding skills than I do, bit nobody else wanted to even try and teach this course to my rural district--- I was not the best choice to teach Java but I was the only choice-- take that as you will and thank you guys for answering my first question nicely. Stack Overflow has become a goto source of information (after Oracle) for my class, but my students often fear the trollish answers some questions get.-- Thanks again!